# Different Android ViewPager based on user mode

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm currently stumped on how to show a different set of tabs via a ViewPager based on the user mode selected. If I don't change user mode, tabs/fragments/ViewPager behave as expected. If I change usermode (use a different adapter with the ViewPager) the correct number of tabs show up but the fragments in each tab do not update correctly. Below is code. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Using on Resume for all the magic. onCreate is normal Layout setup.**

```
// -------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(isActivityForResult){
        return;
    }

    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString("userMode", "").equalsIgnoreCase("buyer")) {
        TextView title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mfm_main_header_title);
        title.setText(R.string.buyer_main_fragment_title);
        adapter = new BuyerSectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    } else if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString("userMode", "").equalsIgnoreCase("seller")) {
        TextView title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mfm_main_header_title);
        title.setText(R.string.seller_main_fragment_title);
        adapter = new SellerSectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    }

    setUpViewTabs(adapter);
    setNavigationDrawer();
}


// Set up tabs for either buyer or seller perspectives
// -------------------------------------------------
public void setUpViewTabs(PagerAdapter adapter) {

    // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.themeCommonBGColor));
    tabs.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.themeYellow));
    tabs.setIndicatorHeight(4);
    tabs.setTabBackground(R.drawable.tab_background_statelist);
    tabs.setTabPaddingLeftRight(0);
    tabs.setAllCaps(true);
    tabs.setShouldExpand(true);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}


// -------------------------------------------------
// -------------------------------------------------
public class BuyerSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public BuyerSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0: {
                return BuyerMyFarmersRootFragment.newInstance();
            }
            case 1: {
                return BuyerMyOrdersFragment.newInstance();
            }

            default: {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                return getString(R.string.buyer_fragment_my_farmers)
                        .toUpperCase(l);
            }
            case 1: {
                return getString(R.string.buyer_fragment_my_orders)
                        .toUpperCase(l);
            }

            default: {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}

// -------------------------------------------------
// -------------------------------------------------
public class SellerSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // -------------------------------------------------
    public SellerSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0: {
                return SellerOrdersRootFragment.newInstance();
            }
            case 1: {
                return SellerProductsRootFragment.newInstance();
            }
            case 2: {
                return SellerCustomersRootFragment.newInstance();
            }
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.seller_fragment_title_orders);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.seller_fragment_title_products);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.seller_fragment_title_customers);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```